# How to view the city/state/country in google analytice ecommerce tracking?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to use google analytice ecommerce for some requirements.
So, I used the following code snippet from google.

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_addTrans',
   '1234',           // order ID - required
   'Womens Apparel', // affiliation or store name
   '28.28',          // total - required
   '1.29',           // tax
   '15.00',          // shipping
   'San Jose',       // city
   'California',     // state or province
   'USA'             // country
]);
_gaq.push(['_addItem',
   '1234',           // order ID - necessary to associate item with transaction
   'DD44',           // SKU/code - required
   'T-Shirt',        // product name
   'Olive Medium',   // category or variation
   '11.99',          // unit price - required
   '1'               // quantity - required
]);
_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);
```

So with this code sample my transactions are getting tracked.

But in my google analytics profile, I'm not seeing the city, state, country. Though other details like order_id, shipping, etc SKU are getting tracked.

Please let me know if you have any idea on this.

Thanks,
Uttam

Answer (score 3):

> All other variables within the addTrans method are optional.
>
> - The affiliate field is not required, and was removed from the Google
>     Analytics Ecommerce reports. You can still use the affiliate field for
>     custom reports and filtering.
> - Tax and shipping appear in the transactions report if you have access
>     to those variables.
> - **The city, state, and country are currently not being used by Google
>     Analytics, but the information is still being collected. You can
>     however use these fields within the profile filters if you have a use
>     for them.**

Source: http://www.roirevolution.com/blog/2009/05/stressing_about_your_ga_ecommerce.php